# How to get 2 mouse pointers for Linux 10 (buster) that can be kept after reboot

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mouse

I split my monitor in two so that two people can use it simultaneously. In addition to that I wanted to have an independent mouse cursor for each window. I tried the *xinput* method but it only worked temporarily and I had to enter the command lines in the terminal after each shutdown. You may have a look at it here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MPX .

Moreover the cursor is a cross (and not a common arrow) and it keeps flickering all the time.
I have also tried to find a configuration file in /etc/X11/ or in /dev/input to add the second mouse device but I found nothing there. Here is a screenshot to illustrate the situation:

[image: screenshot 1]
Cursors do not appear when taking a screenshot, thus I captured them with phone:
[image: cursors]

Comment: X has the concept of multiple screens (:0 and :1). Each of these are fully independent of each other, and this is exactly what you want: You want two X-terminals running on a single server. I no longer have the skills to setup this, but hopefully you can find the info given this.